# Why must one wait 48 hours to fly, after scuba diving?

Tags: safety, medical

Is this rule even true and why is it? I'm going to assume it has to do with pressure but can someone give me a good explanation?

Comment: I misread "after _driving_" and I thought WTF?!?

Comment: Trivia: Thhis is the plot [to an episode of House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airborne_%28House%29)

Comment: I seem to remember 24 hours from my diving classes.

Comment: Some diving watches will show "no fly" for some time after diving on the watch face. To remind the diver about that rule.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes It's true. And yes it's related to pressure.

Have you heard of "The bends" or [decompression sickness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompression_sickness)?

As divers go deeper the pressure increases. The longer you dive and deeper you go the more nitrogen is absorbed into your blood as a dissolved gas. As you return to the surface the pressure reduces and the nitrogen reverts to a gas.

This decompression needs to be done slowly so the nitrogen can pass back out through your lungs.  If you ascend too fast the nitrogen can form bubbles in your blood (Just like when you open a bottle of coke.) which can be painful and possibly fatal.

Even once you have finished diving you will still have residual nitrogen in your blood which will take time to release.

Air pressure reduces further when you fly. If you finished a dive and got in a plane the rapid climb in altitude would result in a drop in pressure similar to a rapid ascent while diving. So you would run the risk of getting the bends.

Small planes aren't pressurized. But even pressurized planes might not maintain atmospheric pressure when flying.

This topic should have been covered if you have taken a dive course.

Comment: This all makes perfect sense but, since the question includes an explicit "Is this rule even true?", it would be good to include a couple of references, too.

Comment: It's of course an imprecise rule. The partial nitrogen pressure in your blood determines whether you can fly, and that pressure depends on the dive profile. Then there's the nitrogen buildup in tissue (especially fat) which further complicates the analysis. [Some background](http://www.rescuediver.org/med/bends.htm). 48 hours is just keeping it safe for normal diving.

Comment: *'migt not maintain...'* In practice, planes are almost never pressurized to 1 atm, but usually about 0.75 atm.

Comment: Waiting 48 hours seems overkill. The French Federation recommends 12 hours after a single dive, 24 hours after two or more dives (See Federico's answer for PADI).
Dive computers compute this time from your actual dives; I have never seen more than 20 hours displayed.

Comment: +1 This topic should have been covered if you have taken a dive course.

Comment: Yeah, passenger aircraft are normally pressurized to pressures that are equivalent to 6,000-8,000 ft. altitude. Keeping surface pressure at 35,000 ft or more would require a **very** strong fuselage, which would weigh a lot more and, therefore, waste a lot of additional fuel.

Comment: It's interesting that I was taught 48 hours when I took an aeronautics exam which was in France, @ChristianLescuyer!

Comment: @ChristianLescuyer I think that's the point - make it absolute overkill to make sure. If 20 hours is the longest time you've ever seen a dive computer come up with, then 24 hours is still within a reasonable percentage of that. Rather than teach people a more complex rule involving the number of dives, how long they lasted, etc. it's just simpler to come up with a single value for people to remember that's *definitely* going to be safe in pretty much *all* scenarios. 48 hours is the highest value you've ever seen, doubled, rounded up to the nearest full day. *Definitely* safe.

Comment: "nitrogen is absorbed into your blood as a liquid"  would better be described as "as a dissolved gas".  Liquid nitrogen would, I hope, never be associated with bodily fluids.  See last scenes of *Terminator II:  Judgement Day*

Comment: @ChristianLescuyer - The dive computers use algorithms to determine the 'likely' remaining dissolved nitrogen in your body.  It likely uses multiple ingress/egress profiles to represent the different tissue types in your body.  These models are based on theories and can be mitigated by a variety of factors including hydration, drugs, %age of body fat, muscle tone, etc.  They each have their own safety margins and can vary widely.  The 48-hour rule is meant to be reasonably certain one shouldn't experience ill effects from flying (which might include emergency cabin depressurization.)

Comment: The Benz? Ah, what a nice car.

Comment: Thanks to all for adding detail and clarifications to my answer. I'm a bit limited using a mobile app.

Comment: Nitrogen is absorbed in virtually all tissues in your body, not just blood. (although blood is the transport medium that moves nitrogen in and out of your body).   Dive computers use numeric models to track how quickly nitrogen is absorbed into and released from about 13 different major tissues (muscle, fat, liver, nerves, etc...), and then show the most significant/most dangerous level.  Some organs absorb nitrogen more readily than others, and release it more slowly than others.

Comment: My own surface interval is now over seven years. Way too long...

Answer (score 11):

To add a reference to Peter's answer, [from PADI](http://www.padi.com/rdp/erdp/General_Rules_using_the_eRDP.htm), one of the institutions that releases Scuba diving certificates:

> **Flying after Diving Recommendations**
>
> **For Dives within the No-Decompression Limits**
>
> - Single Dives: A minimum preflight surface interval of 12 hours is suggested.
> - Repetitive Dives and/or Multi-Day Dives: A minimum preflight surface interval of 18 hours is suggested.
>
> **For Dives requiring decompression stops**:
>
> A minimum preflight surface interval of greater than 18 hours is suggested.

Comment: These are "suggestions" by diving organizations, for divers who want to fly.  How about suggestions from flying organizations for pilots who want to dive?

Comment: @User58220 is a bit more common for a diver to have to take a plane than the other way around. Also, if you are a diver that wants to fly as a passenger you will not get the information that is given only to pilots. With the current method all interested people are informed (all people that scuba AND fly have to take the scuba course), with yours many are left without information (not all people that scuba also take pilot lectures).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is *why* one should wait before flying.

Comment: @DJohnM: "First, get out of the airplane."

Answer (score 9):

It's not just blood, but soft tissue generally.

48 hours is extremely conservative - recreational (single tank of air, 40metre maximum depth) diving guidelines say only 24 hours.

Don't forget altitude (lakes at > 300metres) diving also affects [No-Decompression Limits](http://scuba.about.com/od/DiveTheory/p/What-Is-A-No-Decompression-Limit.htm).

Answer (score 2):

When diving, your body absorbs nitrogen gas. As you ascend towards the surface, your body releases that gas.  If it is released too quickly, you'll get "The Bends".

Modern dive computers model the body as a series of different tissues: fat, muscle, liver, cartilage, brain/nerves, bone marrow, etc. Different dive computers will model different tissues, typically between 8 and 20 tissues.

Each of these tissues absorbs, retains, and releases nitrogen at different rates. The dive computer will track a number of different tissues, but show you only the most critical of the tissues (eg, the one that will take the longest to off-gas to a safe level). Depending on how long you've spent at various depths, the critical tissue will change.  This is guidance for just returning to the surface safely.

Other factors affect each individuals off-gassing rates, such as BMI, general health, specific metabolism, and alcohol consumption.

When you later fly, you're going to even less pressure, and your tissues will off-gas even more.  If you're flying in a typical pressurized commercial jet, you'll be at around 8,000 ft pressure-altitude.  But if you're in an un-pressurized charter flight, you could easily hit 10,000 - 16,000 feet.
Many people have trouble understanding that a "small" plane will actually hit a higher pressure-altitude at 14,000 feet, than a "big" jet at 30,000 feet.

If you haven't been doing extreme diving, and are flying pressurized, then 24 hours is safe for a normally healthy person.  If you're flying un-pressurized above 10,000ft, then 24 hours *may* be safe.  But because The Bends depends on many subtle factors and is unpredictable, 48 hours is considered much safer.

This leads to the typical dive planning advice that you should begin with your most aggressive (deepest, longest) dives first, and use your easier dives later in the trip.  Your body can continue to off-gas from your most deepest dive even during your subsequent, shallower dives.   This is a little contrary to human nature, as many people want to begin at an easier level, and get more aggressive with each dive as their comfort level grows.  But that only sets up the body for a high N<sub>2</sub> load, adding more and more with each dive.

If you have any aggravating factors, such as poor health, significant fat (BMI), alcohol consumption, or a prior incident with decompression, then I would avoid the more aggressive dives and plan on as much time as practical before even a pressurized flight.   For many recreational divers, this simply translates to "no diving and no drinking on the last day of a trip:  Just go sightseeing, or stay on the beach"

---

*Credentials*: Certified NAUI, PADI, and SSI; Trained Recuse Diver; Experienced with Deep, Night, Dry Suit.  (but mostly retired and above the surface now).

Answer (score 1):

By every recommendation I've ever seen 48hrs is extremely liberal for recreational divers.  I went on my first dive trip with my parents when I was 12 years old and our rule was to quit diving at least 24 hours before your flight.  It is related to pressure and it all depends on how much time you've spent and at what depth.  The deeper you go, the quicker you build nitrogen in your tissues and the more time you'll need to allow for that nitrogen to dissipate.  If you spend enough time at depth there is even a recommendation to make a safety-stop during your dive (typically 5-15 minutes at about 30ft for recreational diving) as a best-effort to avoid the bends and surface decompression.  The U.S. Navy created classification charts that indicate your relative nitrogen absorption.  Here are some resources hosted by NOAA, one of them being a PDF specifically covering this topic.

http://www.ndc.noaa.gov/dp_forms.html

http://www.ndc.noaa.gov/pdfs/USNDeco3.pdf